How does the EKG vector algebra work?
I know this question might be waaay off-topic and nobody here cares about it but I'm trying to help my fiance that is a med student.
So, doctors sum vectors in a really weird way on an EKG/ECG:

Basically, they sum based on the orthogonal directions of each vector instead of decomposition on two already orthogonal axis.
And even though I think I got it, I want to understand the following: If I sum them the usual way on an $xy$ system, the angles are preserved (or so I think based on examples) but the lengths are really different, why is that?
Is that because their coordinate system is like this?

It seems that there is a jump from $+180º$ to $-180º$ and that seems like a candidate for me.
If anyone has already asked a similar question and has a semi-rigorous answer, I'd love to hear it

Could you give some more context? What are those "vectors"?

Do you have, say, a link to an article which "sums" vectors in a non-standard way?  For that matter, do "vectors" have the usual meaning ?

Well, basically these arrows are the amplitude measurements of leads that you position in certain parts of the body, they find the resultant measurement like the illustrations.
Well, in all of the textbooks I could find there was no step-by-step algebra, they just throw some equations and illustrations and there is no clear justification of how they do that rigourosly.

"amplitude measurements"  sound like scalar quantities...what direction does an amplitude have?  And, regardless of the level of rigor, please attach a link to some instance in which the computation you are questioning was performed.

Perhaps this is what you are speaking of.  I didn't study it carefully, but it appears to be a shorthand for determining (or maybe just describing) the location of leads placed on a patient.

@lulu https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/

Thanks.  That seems more or less the same as the reference I provided, the my reference looks more introductory.  Maybe it's useful for that reason?

This is an oddball question for this site. FWIW, the 12 lead orientation is a mixture of a lateral arc on the chest and triangular coronal dipoles, noised with tech placement and unique bodies and of course the heart orientation and vasculature, this will be amply covered in med school cards courses. It’s not really amenable to vector addition in a meaningful, precise sense, the aVL III etc leads are automatically computed in the EKG machine without really knowing where they are. Reading them is mostly a visual skill.

Meaning of EKG ?

It depends on the basis chosen. It is nice to have an orthogonal basis, but it is not necessary. A basis is a set of vectors that are linearly independent and span their space. I see no issue with the way they add vectors. Notice that $\pm 90^\circ$ vectors can not be chosen as a basis because they are linearly dependent.

@JeanMarie  Electro Cardiogram   Sometimes ECG but I think EKG is more common (in the States, anyway).

@CroCo but the sum of two vectors (if it is a sum indeed) should be basis independent (that is, if I use orthogonal components to sum the norm of the sum should be the same if I use another basis), this doesn't happen here

@JeanMarie: ECG vs EGK just English vs German cardio vs kardio, I think EKG predates - electrocardiogram
